# How to store webhook data to database using php?

Tags: php, sql, database, webhooks

Im new to webhooks, I saw few tutorials already but I still have no idea what I need to do. I have this webhooks data that I need to read in php and save to a database. I will not upload the whole list so things will be missing out, but the webhook list is right nothing miss typed or wrong with it.

```
{ 
"TransactionID":0, 
"CustomerID":0, 
"StaffID":0, 
"Barcode":"string",  
[ 
  { 
     "TransactionItemID":0, 
     "TransactionID":0, 
 }], 

"MiscProductItems":[], 
"Tenders": 
[ { 
     "TransactionID":0, 
      "TypeID":0, 
}], 
         "BaseItems":
```

php

I saw the following tutorial such as the below, but I dont understand what it does, is it right to have 'php://input'?

I want to get the value of the Barcode, how would I do this? Any help would be great appreciate as I have a headache already trying to figure this out.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$action = json_decode($json, true);
$action_t = $action->Barcode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that string is not in JSON format. Look up the basic JSON format [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp). JSON must start with a `{` for objects or maps and `[` for a list. There is no way that

```
CompleteTransaction
{
```

is a valid JSON. A refactoring that code, a valid JSON would look like this:

```
{
"CompleteTransaction":
{ 
"TransactionID":0, 
"CustomerID":0, 
"StaffID":0, 
"Barcode":"string",  
[ 
  { 
     "TransactionItemID":0, 
     "TransactionID":0, 
 }], 

"MiscProductItems":[], 
"Tenders": 
[ { 
     "TransactionID":0, 
      "TypeID":0, 
}], 
         "BaseItems": ".."
}
}
```

The PHP `json_decode` function will return a `null` for you. Reading the `php://input` depends on what kind of content type request headers you will have. If the headers are other than `text/plain`, php will only be able to read the post data from `php://input`. Also, calling `json_decode()` with `true` as a second parameter, it creates an `array`, not `stdObject`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I really need some help with this im stuck and i dont know what to do, the string is definitely in json format. I didnt wrote this, this is from a company that I need to interact with. I just didnt paste all the code here as it is too big, as i explained above. But pass the string json format. say everything were fine, how do I manage to get the Barcode value? I been trying everything and I just failed! :(

Comment: I deleted the complete transaction as i dont think it is on the string.

Comment: Please help! pls pls pls